# Check progress of multiple BackgroundWorker

Tags: wpf, progress-bar, backgroundworker

So I create multiple BackgroundWorkers using loop:

```
  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(item);
  }
```

Now I just can't figure how do I check that all those workers finished their job ?

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy` ...

Comment: Thanks but wouldn't that check only one instance of BackgroundWorker ?   I can compare list.Count with some variable updated once each worker finish jobFinished++; but there might be some more elegant way;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may keep a list of active workers and let each worker remove itself when finished:

```
List<BackgroundWorker> workers = new List<BackgroundWorker>();

...

  foreach (var item in list)
  {
    worker = new BackgroundWorker();
    worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
    workers.Add(worker);
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted += delegate(object s, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)s;
        workers.Remove(worker);
    }
    worker.RunWorkerAsync(item);
  }

...

public bool IsWorkDone
{
    get { return workers.Count == 0; }
}
```

If you don't want to pool IsWorkDone, you could raise an event after `workers.Remove(worker)` if list is empty...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `workers` is the variable representing list of workers and `_completedWorkersCount` is the count of workers that have finished their job ....

```
    worker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
    (o, e) =>
     {
         _completedWorkersCount = workers.Where(w => !w.IsBusy).Count();
     };
```