# Multiple BackgroundWorker not always competing

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I need to do lots (over 100,000) of ADO writes to a MySQL database.  If I do this one at a time it will take hours (not acceptable).  So figured I could break them into batches of 20 writes at a time into `BackgroundWorker`. The problem is that while it writes all the records to the database it does not exit out of the method. This means the only way I am to know if the system was completed was by looking at the database.

The code that creates all the `BackgroundWorker`;

```
ObservableCollection<MyClass> mObj = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
int recordsPerWorker= 20;
int i = 0;
int loop = 1;
int nLoops = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)numItms / (double)recordsPerWorker);
int remain = numItms % recordsPerWorker;
foreach (var x in MyObject)
{
    mObj.Add(x);
    i++;
    if (loop == nLoops)
        recordsPerWorker = remain;
    if (i == recordsPerWorker)
    {
        loop++;
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += AddWoker_DoWork;
        worker.RunWorkerCompleted += Worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(mObj);
        mObj = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
       i = 0;
    } 
}
while (completeWorkers != nLoops)
{
}
```

Then Worker_RunWorkerCompleted being;

```
private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    completeWorkers++;
}
```

[I have tried this method as well with the same results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947384/check-progress-of-multiple-backgroundworker?answertab=active#tab-top)

I could be going around this all wrong, so please point me in a different direction.

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that your while loop never exits as `completeWorkers` is never equal to `nLoops`. Have you debugged to find out the values of both?

Comment: Yes, you are going about it wrong.  That while-loop is probably just creating deadlock, preventing the RunWorkerCompleted event from firing.  Never hang the UI thread.  Creating such a thread explosion is not healthy anyway and unlikely to speed it up at all.  They'll just take turns waiting for a lock inside MySQL.  Google "mysql bulk insert" to get somewhere.  And whatever you do, ensure that nobody is waiting for this because it is always going to be similar to watching grass grow.